Rating Calculation Issue for Internal and External Services in Laravel
I'm encountering a puzzling issue with calculating ratings for internal and external services in my Laravel application. I have two sets of code that retrieve services based on their type and then calculate ratings for these services. However, I'm getting inconsistent results, and some of the ratings are coming out as 0 when they shouldn't be.
Here's the setup:
I have two sets of code to retrieve services:
A.
$services_internal = Service::join('offices', 'services.office_id', '=', 'offices.id')
    ->where('offices.cluster_id', $cluster_id)
    ->where('service_type', 'internal')
    ->get();

$services_external = Service::join('offices', 'services.office_id', '=', 'offices.id')
    ->where('offices.cluster_id', $cluster_id)
    ->where('service_type', 'external')
    ->get();

B.
$services_internal = Service::where('office_id', 5)
    ->where('service_type', 'internal')
    ->get();
$services_external = Service::where('office_id', 5)
    ->where('service_type', 'external')
    ->get();

Then, I have a method rating() in my Service model that calculates the rating for a service based on responses from respondents:
    public function rating($academic_year, $semester)
    {
        $sqd_results = Response::selectRaw('COUNT(responses.respondent_id) as total_respondents')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN responses.rate = 5 THEN 1 END) as strongly_agree')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN responses.rate = 4 THEN 1 END) as agree')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN responses.rate = 0 THEN 1 END) as na_scores')
            ->join('respondents', 'responses.respondent_id', '=', 'respondents.id')
            ->join('questionnaires', 'responses.questionnaire_id', '=', 'questionnaires.id')
            ->join('questionnaire_types', 'questionnaires.questionnaire_type_id', '=',                'questionnaire_types.id')
            ->where('respondents.academic_year', $academic_year)
            ->where('respondents.semester', $semester)
            ->where('respondents.service_id', $this->id)
            ->where('questionnaires.questionnaire_type_id', 2)
            ->get()->first();

        // Accessing data
        $totalRespondents = $sqd_results->total_respondents;


        $strongly_agree = $sqd_results->strongly_agree;
        $agree = $sqd_results->agree;
        $naScores = $sqd_results->na_scores;

        if (($totalRespondents - $naScores) <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Perform further calculations
        $final_results = ($strongly_agree + $agree) / ($totalRespondents - $naScores) * 100;

        return number_format($final_results, 1);
    }

The issue is that when I use the code from set A, all ratings for internal services come out as 0, whereas when I use the code from set B, some ratings for internal services are calculated correctly. However, in both cases, the ratings for "Service A" and "Service B" always come out as 0.
sample runs:
A:
"internal" => array:4 [▼
    "Service X" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
    "Service Y" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
    "Service Z" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
    "Service A" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
  ]
  "external" => array:2 [▼
    "Service M" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
    "Service N" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
  ]

B:
"internal" => array:4 [▼
    "Service X" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => "94.4"
    ]
    "Service Y" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
    "Service Z" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
    "Service A" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
  ]
  "external" => array:2 [▼
    "Service M" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => "100.0"
    ]
    "Service N" => array:1 [▼
      "rating" => 0
    ]
  ]

I've checked the data in the database, and there are responses available for these services, so the issue seems to be with how the data is being retrieved or how the ratings are being calculated.
Can anyone provide insight into why I might be getting these inconsistent results and how I can ensure accurate ratings for all services?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
